# Adding more than one popup marker - Openlayers map

Tags: javascript, dictionary, popup, openlayers

I have created a marker with a popup using openlayers. It all works fine but I cen't figure out how to add another marker in a different location. Here is my JS:

```
var marker = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        features: [
        new ol.Feature({
            geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([-2.123666, 52.504650]))
        })
        ]
    })
});
```

```
var container = document.getElementById('popup');
 var content = document.getElementById('popup-content');
 var closer = document.getElementById('popup-closer');

 var overlay = new ol.Overlay({
     element: container,
     autoPan: true,
     autoPanAnimation: {
         duration: 250
     }
 });
 map.addOverlay(overlay);

 closer.onclick = function() {
     overlay.setPosition(undefined);
     closer.blur();
     return false;
 };
 
 map.on('singleclick', function (event) {
     if (map.hasFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel) === true) {
         var coordinate = event.coordinate;

         content.innerHTML = '<b>Barrow Hill and Tansey Green</b><br />I am a popup.';
         overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
     } else {
         overlay.setPosition(undefined);
         closer.blur();
     }
 });
```

and my html:

```
<div id="mymap">
<div id="popup" class="ol-popup">
     <a href="#" id="popup-closer" class="ol-popup-closer"></a>
     <div id="popup-content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are may ways to do this. To add multiple markers based on your existing code, add additional features to the array of features, with an additional property for the `popup` content (assuming you want it to vary by the location):

```
var marker = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    features: [
      new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([-2.123666, 52.504650])),
        html: '<b>Barrow Hill and Tansey Green</b><br />I am a popup.'
      }),
      new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([-2.12, 52.504])),
        html: '<b>Marker 2</b><br />I am a popup.'
      }),
      new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([-2.13, 52.51])),
        html: '<b>Marker 3</b><br />I am a popup.'
      })
    ]
  })
});
```

Then change your popup opener function to find the data from the clicked location and display it in the popup:

```
map.on('singleclick', function(event) {
  if (map.hasFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel) === true) {
    var coordinate = event.coordinate;
    var features = map.getFeaturesAtPixel(event.pixel);
    content.innerHTML = features[0].getProperties().html;
    overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
  } else {
    overlay.setPosition(undefined);
    closer.blur();
  }
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/5uLpkr7w/)

[image: screenshot of map with a popup displayed]

**code snippet:**

```js
var marker = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: new ol.source.Vector({
    features: [
      new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([-2.123666, 52.504650])),
        html: '<b>Barrow Hill and Tansey Green</b><br />I am a popup.'
      }),
      new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([-2.12, 52.504])),
        html: '<b>Marker 2</b><br />I am a popup.'
      }),
      new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([-2.13, 52.51])),
        html: '<b>Marker 3</b><br />I am a popup.'
      })
    ]
  })
});
//OSM layer creation
var OSMmap = new ol.layer.Tile({ // TileLayer({
  source: new ol.source.OSM(),
});
//Map initiation
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'mymap',

  layers: [OSMmap, marker], //cities],

  view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([15, 0]),
    zoom: 2
  }),

});

var container = document.getElementById('popup');
var content = document.getElementById('popup-content');
var closer = document.getElementById('popup-closer');

var overlay = new ol.Overlay({
  element: container,
  autoPan: true,
  autoPanAnimation: {
    duration: 250
  }
});
map.addOverlay(overlay);

closer.onclick = function() {
  overlay.setPosition(undefined);
  closer.blur();
  return false;
};

map.on('singleclick', function(event) {
  if (map.hasFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel) === true) {
    var coordinate = event.coordinate;
    var features = map.getFeaturesAtPixel(event.pixel);
    content.innerHTML = features[0].getProperties().html;
    overlay.setPosition(coordinate);
  } else {
    overlay.setPosition(undefined);
    closer.blur();
  }
});
map.getView().fit(marker.getSource().getExtent(), {
  padding: [40, 16, 40, 16]
});
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#mymap {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#popup {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border: black 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.5.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v6.5.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
<div id="mymap">
  <div id="popup" class="ol-popup">
    <a href="#" id="popup-closer" class="ol-popup-closer"></a>
    <div id="popup-content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Another way to do it](http://www.geocodezip.com/OL_6.5.0_simpleMultipleMarkerExample.html)